# I cannot access in a property of this object

Tags: typescript

I want to find the `questionOption.title === "Ubication"` but I cannot access in the properties of `question_option_history.questionOption` and I don't know why. This is an example:
The code:

```
const dataToFind = locationQuestion.question_option_history;
```

And this is the response:

```
[
{
    "id": 234,
    "answer": "Juan's house",
    "questionOption": {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "Ubication details:"
    }
},
{
    "id": 233,
    "answer": "30.888,-10.111",
    "questionOption": {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Ubication:"
    }
}]
```

So, when I do `question_option_history.questionOption.title` VSCode give me an error telling

> title doesn't exist in QuestionOption[]

(QuestionOption y the entity).

I want to run the array and find what is the `questionOption.title === "Ubication"` and take the `answer` of that object. Because in that object I save the lat and long of the ubication.

This is what I want to do:

```
let dataToFind = locationQuestion.question_option_history.find(option => option.questionOption.title === "Ubication");
```

And take the `answer` of dataToFind, to save the coordinates

Comment: "This is what I want to do:" Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Not sure how to help, bruh. Is the error occurring on the auto-complete? or when you execute your code? Your code snippets are not painting a clear picture - how about you demonstrate with a codepen.

Comment: I fix finally, the error was in the relations between the entities. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```js
type QuestionOptionWithTitleAndId = {id: number; title: string}
type ExtendedQuestionOption = QuestionOption & {questionOption: QuestionOptionWithTitleAndId}
```

```js
const dataToFind = locationQuestion.question_option_history as ExtendedQuestionOption;
```

What you are trying to do is access a property on an object which is not defined inside of the type definition of the object.

In order to tell typescript that the property will actually exist on the object you can either add this directly to your `QuestionOption` type or, in case this `QuestionOption` comes from a library, create a new type by extending the `QuestionObject` type.

Then you can declare your `dataToFind` as this new type, so typescript will know that `questionOption.title` and `questionOption.id` will always be available. Afterwards, it should let you access them properly, and the suggested code (on the bottom of your question) should work fine.